# Check whether there are remaining items in the List while iterating

Tags: java

I'm doing a Bean Validation for a List of conditions:

```
public abstract class BaseMyConditionValidator<T extends Annotation> implements ConstraintValidator<T, List<MyCondition>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(T constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<MyCondition> conditions, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean result = true;
        if (!conditions.isEmpty()){
            int i = 0;
            for (MyCondition cond : conditions){
                if (cond.getJoinPart() != null){
                    if (!hasNext(i, conditions)){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean hasNext(int index, List<MyCondition> conditions){
        try {
            conditions.get(index + 1);
        } catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

My question is is there a simpler approach to deal with:

- Checking if there is still an item next in line during a iteration of a List

Comment: I don't understand this code. Surely hasNext ends up checking for the existence of the current element? Maybe you meant hasNext(i+1)?

Comment: This is very, very odd code. You have a `continue` to avoid incrementing `i`, so each time `cond.getJoinPart()` is not `null`, you get further out of sync (`i` doesn't get increased as the iterator continues). What is it that `isValid` is really meant to check? Why does this need to be so convoluted?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? Every time hasNext returns true you skip incrementing i, is that intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use plain old `Iterator` to iterate through the list, or instead of `hasNext(i, conditions)` just check list length (`i < conditions.size() - 1`)

In the end, instead of iterating through whole list, just check if last element's `JoinPart` is `null` (at least it is what you are doing)

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(List<MyCondition> conditions, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    return conditions.isEmpty() || conditions.get(conditions.size() - 1).getJoinPart() != null;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but the point is if getJoinPart is null its OK that is the last item in the list, if getJoinPart is Not NUll then there should be another item on the list. Otherwise it is considered as invalid.

Comment: @xybrek so basically all elements must have `not null` JointPart except for the last one, which has to have `null` ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, in your case/code you don't need to check whether there is another element in the list. Using for(MyCondition cond : conditions) will iterate over all elements in conditions list. If you need to check what is the size of the list, you can use contidions.size().

Answer (score 0):

Of course!

```
        for (int i = 0; i < conditions.size(); i++){
            cond = conditions.get(i);
            if (cond.getJoinPart() != null){
                if (i < conditions.size()){
                    continue;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

But I don't understand why you would do that... are you just trying to ensure that .getJoinPart() doesn't equal null for every element?